# Rails has_one relationship and simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, polymorphic-associations

Using simple_form to build a nested form for a `WorkoutSet` model with the following fields:

- `intro_video`
- `get_ready`
- `outro_video`
- `WorkoutStep` (another nested model)

I want to be able to select an `intro_video` out of a select

As `WorkoutSet` is inside `Workout`, the forms look like this:
**WorkoutSet.rb**

```
class WorkoutSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :workout_steps, :join_table => :sets_steps, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :workouts, :join_table => :workout_sessions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_steps, allow_destroy: true

  has_one :intro_video_usage, class_name: 'VideoUsage::Intro', as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :intro_video, through: :intro_video_usage, source: :video

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :intro_video

  has_one :get_ready_video_usage, class_name: 'VideoUsage::GetReady', as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :get_ready_video, through: :get_ready_video_usage, source: :video

  has_one :congrats_video_usage, class_name: 'VideoUsage::Congratulations', as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :congrats_video, through: :congrats_video_usage, source: :video
end
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
  %h2 Sets
  .sets.some{ :style => "margin-left: 25px" }
    = f.simple_fields_for :workout_sets do |set|
      = render 'workout_set_fields', f: set
    .links
      .button-row
        = link_to_add_association 'add set', f, :workout_sets
```

**_workout_set_fields.html.haml**

```
.nested-fields
  %h2 New set - #{link_to_remove_association 'Delete', f}
  = f.label :title
  = f.text_field :title

  = f.input :intro_video, :collection => Video.all, :label_method => :title, :value_method => :id, :include_blank => false

  %br
  %br
  #sets.some{ :style => "margin-left: 25px" }
    = f.simple_fields_for :workout_steps do |step|
      = render 'workout_step_fields', f: step
    .links
      .button-row
        = link_to_add_association 'add step', f, :workout_steps
```

The select is rendered and the values looks fine until I save the model whitelisting the following parameters:

```
params.require(:workout).permit(:title, :pro, :image, warmup_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, {main_video_ids: []}], workout_sets_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :title, :intro_video, workout_steps_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, {main_video_ids: []}] ])
```

Also, I notice that in the line `f.input :intro_video` the parameter being sent is `intro_video`, instead of `intro_video_attributes`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get what you are asking

Comment: woops, I forgot to ask the actual question. I want to be able to select an `intro_video` out of a select